# Realpath not working with ../files?

Tags: php, codeigniter, realpath

I am developing under wamp.

```
echo realpath(APPPATH);
```

C:\wamp\www\salsaritmo\system\application

```
echo realpath(APPPATH . '..');
```

C:\wamp\www\salsaritmo\system

```
echo realpath(APPPATH . '../files');  //(which is the one i want)
```

returns nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[realpath() returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Answer (score 1):

Your APPPATH doesn't end with a directory separator, so you're ending up trying to realpath('C:\wamp\www\salsaritmo\system../files'), which obviously isn't valid. Try:

```
   echo realpath(APPPATH . '/../files');
```